# Reading multiple child nodes in XML using openxml (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: openxml

XML Tree is -

```
<OrderLine>
    <Item>ABC</Item>
        <Lot>
            <Serial>SR1</Serial>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        </Lot>
        <Lot>
            <Serial>SR1</Serial>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        </Lot>
</OrderLine>
```

While trying to parse this tree for element values using openxml in SQL Server 2005 (stored procedure) only one  is read.

Here's the code -

```
select item, lots
from openxml(@intDataAreaRoot, 'OrderLine', 2)
        with    (   item    nvarchar(31)    'Item',
                    lots    xml             'Lot'
        )
```

I use this to declare a cursor and then parse & process as many lines as there may be in the tree. But each "fetch" brings only one "Lot" node. I need to process all "Lot" nodes under the "OrderLine" node.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, using the **native XQuery** support in SQL Server 2005:

```
DECLARE @intDataAreaRoot  XML = '<OrderLine>
    <Item>ABC</Item>
        <Lot>
            <Serial>SR1</Serial>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        </Lot>
        <Lot>
            <Serial>SR2</Serial>
            <Quantity>21</Quantity>
        </Lot>
</OrderLine>'

SELECT
    Item = @intDataAreaRoot.value('(/OrderLine/Item)[1]', 'varchar(25)'),
    xc.value('(Serial)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    xc.value('(Quantity)[1]', 'int')
FROM
    @intDataAreaRoot.nodes('/OrderLine/Lot') AS XT(XC)
```

This gives me an output of :

```
Item    (No column name)    (No column name)
---------------------------------------------
ABC            SR1                  1
ABC            SR2                 21
```

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile I got a reference to the <OrderLine> node itself in the openxml/with clause.  with (lineref   xml   '.') I can now open another cursor only for the lots and then process them.